# Merge unique values to array from array of arrays

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have array like this:

```
[
  [
    {id:1, name:'xxx'}
  ],
  [
    {id:2, name:'xxx'},
    {id:1, name:'xxx'}
  ],
  [
    {id:2, name:'xxx'},
    {id:1, name:'xxx'},
    {id:3, name:'xxx'}
  ]
]
```

I need pick just objects with unique id and merge them into one array. Each object has `id` property, so I tried this:

```
_.(data).union().uniqBy(o => o.id).value()
```

but it gives me wrong result.

My required output should be like this:

```
[{id:1, name:'xxx'}, {id:2, name:'xxx'}, {id:3, name:'xxx'}]
```

Can you help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: Post a real example (input data) and the expected result.

Comment: Would `_.uniqBy(_.flattenDeep(data), "id")` do what you're wanting?

Comment: @CRice: Seems right to me.

Comment: @Ele I edited question, check it please.

Comment: @CRice I'll try it and give you response

Comment: @CRice Yes it works :) you get put this as answer if you can :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`_.flatten()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#flatten) to merge the sub arrays into a single array and then apply `_.uniqBy()`:

```js
const data = [[{"id":1,"name":"xxx"}],[{"id":2,"name":"xxx"},{"id":1,"name":"xxx"}],[{"id":2,"name":"xxx"},{"id":1,"name":"xxx"},{"id":3,"name":"xxx"}]];

const result = _(data)
  .flatten()
  .uniqBy('id')
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```